# CoreFoundation printing Unicode characters

Tags: c++, c, macos, core-foundation

I have the current code and it does seem to work except for the fact CFShow doesn't translate the unicode UTF8 encoding of [\u00e9](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=unicode%20hex%20e9) to é

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main()
{

    char *s = "This is a test of unicode support: fiancée\n";
    CFTypeRef cfs = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, s, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFShow(cfs);

}
```

Output is

```
This is a test of unicode support: fianc\u00e9e
                                        |____|
                                           > é doesn't output properly.
```

How do I instruct CFShow that it is unicode? printf handles it fine when it is a c string.

Comment: If `CFShow` didn't already believe that the string is Unicode, it wouldn't be interpreting the characters as such and using `\u` escapes. You would see stuff like `\xC3\xA9`.

Answer (score 5):

`CFShow()` is only for debugging. It's deliberately converting non-ASCII to escape codes in order to avoid ambiguity. For example, "é" can be expressed in two ways: as U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE or as U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT. If `CFShow()` were to emit the UTF-8 sequence, your terminal would likely present it as "é" and you wouldn't be able to tell which variant was in the string. That would undermine the usefulness of `CFShow()` for debugging.

Why do you care what the output of `CFShow()` so long as it you understand what the content of the string is?

Comment: To use it as output to the console without having to resort to C libraries and using printf. So a companion to a way to output to the console with Win API functions using Mac OS X API Core Foundation.

Comment: @Zimm3r: That's not what `CFShow` is for. `CFShow` is for peeking at a string's contents for debugging purposes, not for regular output. You should ask a separate question about the correct way to write a CFString to stdout or stderr. Send me the link and I'll answer it.

Comment: `CFShow()` is not suitable for general printing of strings (or anything else). As I say, it's a debugging function. If you're determined to avoid C libraries and stdio, you can use `CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation()` or `CFStringGetCString()` to get a UTF-8-encoded byte buffer and use `write()` or the like to output it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that `CFShow` knows that the string is Unicode, but doesn't know how to format Unicode for the console.  I doubt that you can do anything but look for an alternative, perhaps `NSLog`.

Comment: NSLog is objective c though isn't it? I'm trying to stick to C and C++ so I can easily use it in assembly (something Apple seems to shun).

Comment: Yes, `NSLog` is Objective-C.  But you could write a wrapper function that takes a CFStringRef and passes it to `NSLog`, and thus confine the Objective-C to one little file.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid objective c, which seems impossible sense apple uses it so much sadly. Oh well now trying to find how to call it inside assembly; looks like lots og objc_msgSend calls.

Comment: Now that I look at it, the declaration is `extern "C" void NSLog(NSString *format, ...)`.  So if you know how to call a C function with a variable number of arguments in assembly, you should be all set.

Comment: @Zimm3r: `NSLog` is a C function provided by the Foundation framework. Just because *most* of the framework is Objective-C classes doesn't mean it's nothing but. There are actually [rather a lot of Foundation functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/).