# Writing a CFSTR to the terminal in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation

How best would I output the following code

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> // Needed for CFSTR
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *c_string = "Hello I am a C String. :-).";
    CFStringRef cf_string = CFStringCreateWithCString(0, c_string, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    // output cf_string
    //

}
```

Comment: Perhaps `CFShow(cf_string)`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Doesn't output unicode properly see first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667799/corefoundation-printing-unicode-characters

Comment: @PaulR I am doing the opposite I wish to print a CFSTR not a char * (C String) which I could do with printf, however I am trying to use CoreFoundation to print it. Similar to what can be done with the Win32API.

Comment: I think that's the only option; you could create a `CFWriteStreamRef` of `stdout`, but then that only allows writing of byte buffers anyway.

Comment: @Zimm3r: you just have to convert the `CFStringRef` to a `char *` (hence the duplicate flag) and then use `puts` or whatever to output the C string. What is your objection to doing that ?

Comment: I am trying to use Mac OS X API's from CoreFoundation similar to http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65224-intro-to-win32-assembly-using-nasm-part-3/

Comment: CoreFoundation does not provide an API to print a CFStringRef directly. If you want to print it, you must convert it to a C string in the encoding you want and print that. Therefore, the duplicate link does mostly answer your question, you just need to print the result.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a C string. This question is not a duplicate of a question about that task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no API to write a CFString directly to any file (including stdout or stderr), because you can only write bytes to a file. Characters are a (somewhat) more ideal concept; they're too high-level to be written to a file. It's like saying “I want to write these pixels”; you must first decide what format to write them in (say, PNG), and then encode them in that format, and then write that data.

So, too, with characters. You must encode them as bytes in some format, then write those bytes.

#### Encoding the characters as bytes/data

First, you must pick an encoding. For display on a Terminal, you probably want UTF-8, which is `kCFStringEncodingUTF8`. For writing to a file… you usually want UTF-8. In fact, unless you specifically need something else, you almost always want UTF-8.

Next, you must encode the characters as bytes. Creating a C string is one way; another is to create a CFData object; still another is to extract bytes (not null-terminated) directly.

- To create a C string, use [the `CFStringGetCString` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCString).
- To extract bytes, [use the `CFStringGetBytes` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetBytes).

You said you want to stick to CF, so we'll skip the C string option (which is less efficient anyway, since whatever calls `write` is going to have to call `strlen`)—it's easier, but slower, particularly when you use it on large strings and/or frequently. Instead, we'll create CFData.

Fortunately, CFString provides an API to create a CFData object from the CFString's contents. Unfortunately, this only works for creating an [external representation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation). You probably do not want to write this to stdout; it's only appropriate for writing out as the entire contents of a regular file.

So, we need to drop down a level and [get bytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetBytes) ourselves. This function takes a buffer (region of memory) and the size of that buffer in bytes.

*Do not* use `CFStringGetLength` for the size of the buffer. That counts characters, not bytes, and the relationship between number of characters and number of bytes is not always linear. (For example, some characters can be encoded in UTF-8 in a single byte… but not all. Not nearly all. And for the others, the number of bytes required varies.)

The correct way is to call `CFStringGetBytes` *twice*: once with no buffer (`NULL`), whereupon it will simply tell you how many bytes it'll give you (without trying to write into the buffer you haven't given it); then, you create a buffer of that size, and then call it again with the buffer.

You *could* create a buffer using `malloc`, but you want to stick to CF stuff, so we'll do it this way instead: [create a CFMutableData object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataCreateMutable) whose capacity is the number of bytes you got from your first `CFStringGetBytes` call, [increase its length](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataIncreaseLength) to that same number of bytes, then [get the data's mutable byte pointer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataGetMutableBytePtr). That pointer is the pointer to the buffer you need to write into; it's the pointer you pass to the second call to `CFStringGetBytes`.

To recap the steps so far:

- Call `CFStringGetBytes` with no buffer to find out how big the buffer needs to be.
- Create a CFMutableData object of that capacity and increase its length up to that size.
- Get the CFMutableData object's mutable byte pointer, which is your buffer, and call `CFStringGetBytes` again, this time with the buffer, to encode the characters into bytes in the data object.

#### Writing it out

To write bytes/data to a file in pure CF, you must use [CFWriteStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/).

Sadly, there's no CF equivalent to nice Cocoa APIs like `[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput]`. The only way to create a write stream to stdout is to create it using the path to stdout, wrapped in a URL.

You can create a URL easily enough from a path; the path to the standard output device is `/dev/stdout`, so to create the URL looks like this:

```
CFURLRef stdoutURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("/dev/stdout"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, /*isDirectory*/ false);
```

(Of course, like everything you Create, you need to Release that.)

Having a URL, you can then [create a write stream for the file so referenced](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamCreateWithFile). Then, you must [open the stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamOpen), whereupon you can [write the data to it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamWrite) (you will need to [get the data's byte pointer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataGetBytePtr) and [its length](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataGetLength)), and finally [close the stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamClose).

Note that you *may* have missing/un-displayed text if what you're writing out doesn't end with a newline. `NSLog` adds a newline for you when it writes to stderr on your behalf; when you write to stderr yourself, you have to do it (or live with the consequences).

So:

- [Create a URL that refers to the file you want to write to.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath)
- [Create a stream that can write to that file.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamCreateWithFile)
- [Open the stream.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamOpen)
- [Write bytes to the stream.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamWrite) (You can do this as many times as you want, or [do it asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop).)
- When you're all done, [close the stream.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamClose)