# How to display UTF8 string in OS X Terminal

Tags: objective-c, macos, utf-8, printf, nslog

I can't believe I couldn't find a solution to this very simple issue. I have a command line tool in Objective C, and need to display UTF8 strings (with non-English characters) in the console. I can't use NSLog as it also display process information, PID, timestamp etc. too. printf doesn't handle non-English characters well.

How can I print non-English characters in the Terminal, without any timestamps? Am I missing something really obvious here, or is such an extremely simple task really non-trivial in OS X?

I've tried:

`printf`: Doesn't display non-English characters.

`NSLog`: Displays PID/timestamp, which I don't want.

`DLog` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311835/811405): Doesn't display non-English characters.

Comment: Could you please paste the code you wrote?

Comment: @Razvan they are regular logging codes. there's nothing to paste. But I've added what I've tried.

Comment: @Razvan it's just regular UTF8 string, for example my name, `@"Can Poyrazoğlu"`. I'll be looking at the library you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
printf("%s\n", [@"Can Poyrazoğlu" UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `macro` you've tried to use depends on `CFShow` which doesn't print Unicode characters but only their escape codes. More information regarding this behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667799/corefoundation-printing-unicode-characters).

So you could either use something else for your `macro` instead of CFShow to print to console without any timestamps or you could use an NSLog replacement library I wrote, [Xcode Logger](https://github.com/codeFi/XcodeLogger) and use its `XLog_NH` logger which prints only the output without any other information.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stdio`:

```
puts([@"Can Poyrazoğlu" UTF8String]);
```

Using `write`:

```
const char* example = [@"Can Poyrazoğlu" UTF8String];
write(STDOUT_FILENO, example, strlen(example));
```